# How to upload a csv file in tensorflow.js in angular project?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, tensorflow.js

For my anguar project I'm trying to upload a csv file from my assets folder with tf.data.csv, but the file is not being recognized by the code meaning, that the created Object is empty.
Is it even possible to upload a csv via tf.data.csv() from assets?
And if yes, how? :)

```
async loadData(){
  const csvUrl = 'assets/tfjs_model/lsm6dsm.csv' as string;
    const csvDataset = tf.data.csv(csvUrl, 
    {
      hasHeader:false, 
      columnNames:["timestamp", "x-axis","y-axis","z-axis"],
    }
    ) as any;
    console.log(csvDataset);
    return csvDataset
  }
```

**Here is what is being printed in the console**:

> base: e {size: null, input: e}
>
> columnConfigs: undefined
>
> columnNamesValidated: false
>
> configuredColumnsOnly: undefined
>
> delimWhitespace: false
>
> delimiter: ","
>
> fullColumnNames: (4) ["timestamp", "x-axis", "y-axis", "z-axis"]
>
> hasHeader: false
>
> input: e {url: "assets/tfjs_model/lsm6dsm.csv", fileOptions: {…}}
>
> size: null
>
> **proto**: t

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course this is possible.
I don't know if you CSV has column headers with "" if so try this

```
async function example(){

// Import from CSV
const dataSet = tf.data.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JuliaStats/RDatasets.jl/master/doc/datasets.csv');

// Extract x and y values to plot
const pointsDataSet = dataSet.map(record => ({
    x: record["\"Rows\""],
    y: record["\"Columns\""]
}));

const points = await pointsDataSet.toArray();

console.log(points);
}

example();
```